# Is vertical alignment for PdfTextFormField possible?

Tags: itext7

At the moment I'm writing a couple of evaluatuation programs with iText.

I have an issue with vertical alignment of form fields.

Does anybody know whether vertical alignment is possible and how?

I want to set vertical alignment to "bottom" instead of standard value "middle".

[image: PdfTextFormField with standard alignment "middle"]

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfTextFormField;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;

public class problem4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fnPdf = "results/problem4.pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fnPdf);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        PdfTextFormField field = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, new Rectangle(40, 200, 150, 50), "fName", "Dirk");
        field.setColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
        field.setFontSize(10);
        field.setJustification(PdfFormField.ALIGN_CENTER);
        // missing vertical alignment bottom
        field.setBorderColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
        field.setBorderWidth(2);
        form.addField(field, page);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.close();
        pdf.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fnPdf));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you very much for this info! Dirk

Comment: Please be aware that vertical alignment is not a PDF feature of regular text fields at all; the situation may differ for richt-text fields.